# onGetViewFactory not called in widget

Tags: java, android, widget

I create listView inside my widget by using RemoteViewsFactory and RemoteViewsService but I have the problem always my widget is empty, when I make debug to my code I note the onGetViewFactory method didn't call never I review my code a lot but I can't see what is wrong in my code.

For fill the list view RemoteViewsFactoryc:

```
public class RemoteViewsFactoryc implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
 //for test
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"hellow",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

WidgetService call RemoteViewsFactoryc:

```
 public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
    @Override
        public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
            return new RemoteViewsFactoryc(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
        }
    }
```

FootballWidget class:

```
public class FootballWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
 @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            RemoteViews widget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.list_widget);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetIds[i]);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
  widget.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.scores_list,intent);
 widget.setEmptyView(R.id.scores_list, R.id.empty_view);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], widget);
        }
    }
}
 @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (scoresAdapter.ACTION_DATA_UPDATED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(
                    new ComponentName(context, getClass()));

            RemoteViews widget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.list_widget);

            widget.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.scores_list,intent);
     }
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
  android:name=".FootballWidget"
  android:icon="@drawable/fottballicon"
  android:label="hi">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"></action>
      <action android:name="com.example.android.football.app.ACTION_DATA_UPDATED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
    android:resource="@xml/app_widget_provider"></meta-data>
</receiver>

<service
  android:name="barqsoft.footballscores.WidgetService"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="false"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?